# ¿Cómo eliminar filas de tabla SQLite a través de una QTableView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código para mostrar una tabla SQLite en una `QTableView`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5 import uic, QtSql,QtGui
import sqlite3

class Principal(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('mostrar_tableview.ui',self)
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.dele)

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/new/Db/Users.db')
        db.open()

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable('Traspasos')
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()
        self.tabla.setModel(self.model)
    def dele(self):

        model = self.model
        model.removeRow()



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

La tabla se muestra correctamente, el problema es que cuando quiero eliminar una fila seleccionada no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas en la firma del método [`removeRow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRow):

```
QAbstractItemModel.removeRow(self, row: int,
                             parent: QModelIndex=QModelIndex()) -> bool
```

lógicamente te falta indicar el índice de la fila (parámetro `row`) a eliminar, el cual puedes obtener mediante el índice de la fila seleccionada actualmente en tu tabla con `self.tabla.currentIndex().row()`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5 import uic, QtSql



class Principal(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mostrar_tableview.ui',self)
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.delete_row)

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/new/Db/Users.db')
        db.open()

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable('Traspasos')
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()
        self.tabla.setModel(self.model)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def delete_row(self):
        index = self.tabla.currentIndex()
        self.model.removeRow(index.row())
        self.model.submitAll()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```